# c# Mysql to Datagridview duplicate values

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a problem with the following code:

```
MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(myConne);
MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("Select * from supplier_data,brands where brands.supplier_id = supplier_data.supplier_id ", conDatabase);
MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
System.Data.DataTable dbdataset = new System.Data.DataTable();
sda.Fill(dbdataset);
BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
dataGridView3.DataSource = bSource;
sda.Update(dbdataset);
```

When it displays into datagridview, if one supplier has two brands, duplicates received data but with other brand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the result by using [group-by](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx), So attach the following at the end of your query

`Group By brands.supplier_id`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to display all brands for one supplier in one datagrindview cell ?